# Non Secure Items on webpage in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, https

I have tried everything I can think of and still getting the insecure items on webpage popup that IE 8 users get when one or more items on the page are not https. All my items on the page are https and I've double checked this using Fiddler. Is anyone able to tell me which item on this page is causing this error?

https://www.ems-us.org/loginredirect2.asp

Answer (score 0):

In style.css you have this class, which is calling a non-secure background image:

```
.menu li a{
background:#136733 url("http://i47.tinypic.com/qp53sw.jpg") bottom right no-repeat;
color:#FFFFFF;
display:block;
font-size : 14px;
font-family : Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;

line-height:25px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px 9px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

The host site doesn't appear to offer https.  Can you copy it locally to your web server and make the reference relative?